# Python Pandas: Series and getting value from data frame counts null entries?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file with 7000 rows and 5 cols.

I have an array of 5000 words, that I want to add to the same CSV file in a new column. I added a column 'originalWord ', and used the `pd.Series` function which added the 5000 words in a single column as I want.

```
allWords=['x' * 5000]
df['originalWord']=pd.Series(allWords)
```

My problem now is I want to get the data in the column 'originalWord' - whether by putting them in an array or accessing the column directly - even though it's 5000 rows only and the file has 7000 rows (with the last 2000 being null values)

```
print(len(df['originalWord']))
```

> 7000

Any idea how to make it reflect the original length 5000 ? Thank you.

Comment: Do you need remove missing values from column? Like `L = df['originalWord'].dropna().tolist()` ?

Comment: @jezrael yes but I was hoping to be permanent, meaning now I did that >df['originalWord']=df['originalWord'].dropna()
> print(len(df['originalWord']))
however len is still 7000, is there's a way to make stored 5000 and whenever I access that column it just sends the 5000 rows not the 7000 without writing dropna() at every access?

Comment: Not understand. do you need remove last 2000 rows filled by missing values? Like `df = df.dropna(subset=['originalWord'])` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, what you're asking for isn't possible. From what I can gather, you have a DataFrame that has 7000 rows and 5 columns, meaning that the index is of size 7000. To this DataFrame, you would like to add a column that has 5000 rows. Since there are in total 7000 rows in the DataFrame, the appended column will have 2000 missing values that would thus be assigned NaN. That's why you see the length as 7000.

In short, there is no way of accessing `df['originalWord']` and automatically exclude all missing values as even that Series has an index of size 7000. The closest you could get to is to write a function that would include `dropna()` if the issue is that you find it bothersome to repeatedly call it.

Comment: Yes exactly as you described, I will just used dropna() every time I reference the columns (I am lucky because I don't have null values in between data, if I did have null values in the 5000 rows and I want to keep them then dropna() would mess that)

Comment: Not necessarily. You could also "filter" them out using their index. Assuming that you would like the first 5000, you could use `df.iloc[:5000]`, to return the DataFrame without the added NaN. That is also a possible option for you if you only care about the rows where `df['originalWord']` has values (i.e the first 5000).